# How do I stack multiple columns into one column in Excel 365 Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I currently have my data in different columns after using a Text To Columns feature. Now what I want to do is to put them all into one column. Can you please advise what formula to use or is there a custom script, please? I have got Office 365 for Mac. I am computer literate but not familiar with using VBA, however if the answer is in VBA if I can kindly ask for some guidance please on how to implement it that'd be great. Thank you

[image: sheet]

Comment: Does the Mac version have `VSTACK`?  `=VSTACK(A4:A9,B4:B9,C4:C9)`

Answer (score 0):

Can the order of the data in this one column be changed?

If yes, please try formula `=INDEX(A:C,ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/3,),MOD(ROW(A1)-1,3)+1)`.

[image]

Please note, the "A:C" means the columns of your source data. Number "3" means 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TOCOL function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/tocol-function-22839d9b-0b55-4fc1-b4e6-2761f8f122ed) to that end.  This function allows controlling the way the input array is scanned as well as how blanks and errors in the input array are handled.

For your specific case you probably want to place, say in the F3 cell (or anywhere else), the following:

```
=TOCOL(A3:C7, 0, TRUE)
```